# Purposes of using Bean instead of model in Spring MVC & Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I saw a tutorial coding using bean instead of model, but didn't explain why need to do so.

> http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-crud-example.html#.V4R1_vl96Un

Anyone know why do this? Any use case for using bean classes?

Some code in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")EmployeeBean employeeBean,
   BindingResult result) {
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService.getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
  model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
  return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
}

private EmployeeBean prepareEmployeeBean(Employee employee){
  EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
  bean.setAddress(employee.getEmpAddress());
  bean.setAge(employee.getEmpAge());
  bean.setName(employee.getEmpName());
  bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
  bean.setId(employee.getEmpId());
  return bean;
 }
```

I'm new to sping mvc, appreciate anyone can explain why to do so...
Thanks.

Comment: May be to separate presentation layer from persistence layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the example, it seems he's just created the 'EmployeeBean' class to return to the front end JSP (presentation layer). This would be to decouple the POJO from the hibernate 'Employee' class, which he's made specifically for mapping the object into hibernate.

More about JavaBeans conventions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

Answer (score -1):

Author wrote the code in such a way that while rendering data to the JSP it converts model class into his custom bean and while inserting data he converts the custom bean to model class.

This could be his idea to introduce his **custom control layer** between the **persistent layer** and **representation layer**. The reason could be to control the flow by adding his custom default values or may be custom validation though this can be possible by Spring using @InitBinder and many other techniques.